# How to make a pivot table from a dataframe that groups by year and count my data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

Hello people i have a question, i have a dataframe with different products and dates, something like this:

| product | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2016 |
| A | 01-02-2016 |
| B | 23-04-2016 |
| B | 22-02-2016 |
| A | 02-12-2017 |
| A | 13-11-2017 |
| B | 12-12-2017 |

What i want to do is create a pivot table that counts how many times product A and B are in each year.

Expected output is something  like this:

| product | 2016 | 2017 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| B | 2 | 1 |

Thank you for your support and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the date is a datetime object you can use `df['date'].dt.year` as your columns in the pivot.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B'],
 'date': ['01-01-2016',
  '01-02-2016',
  '23-04-2016',
  '22-02-2016',
  '02-12-2017',
  '13-11-2017',
  '12-12-2017']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.pivot_table(index='product', columns=df['date'].dt.year, aggfunc='count').droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

print(df)
```

Output

```
date  2016  2017
A        2     2
B        2     1
```